# bpmn2 modeler in Gef

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-gef

I am trying to develop the bpmn2 modeler using GEF alone. I have the emf bpmn2 model in place and really confused of how to use the model and create an fully functional Bpmn2 editor using GEF alone.

I have gone through various tutorials in internet of how to build the graphical editor from emf model, but the emf bpmn2 metamodel is complex and I am stuck in the middle and I face issues when setting the bounds for each shape (`setBounds` and `getBounds`) and it goes on.

The bpmn modeler being developed at the following location (http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/?project=bpmn2) is using graphiti. The bpmn2 modeler I propose is done entirely in GEF (graphical editing framework).

If anyone of you are working towards the same effort or if you know anyone creating bpmn2 modeler entirely in GEF please let me know so that we can put our efforts to accomplish the goal.

You are welcome to share your views and any resource related to this effort.

Answer (score 1):

You can check my ongoing GEF tutorial at [www.vainolo.com](http://www.vainolo.com/). Shows many aspects of creating a complete GEF editor.
If you have problems with the model maybe this is not the correct place to ask.
Good luck!